# names of list with rbind work not correct

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R and one thing I don't understand. Why is this code not working correctly?

If I have:

```
g <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2)
b <- list("hehe", "hoho", "hihi", g)
names(b) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

I got this results. This is ok.

```
$a
[1] "hehe"

$b
[1] "hoho"

$c
[1] "hihi"

$d
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 2
```

When I put in one list more rows names not working good. Here is example:

```
listek <- list()
g <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2)
l <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7)
b <- list("hehe", "hoho", "hihi", g)
d <- list("ddd", "eee", "fff", l)
listek <- rbind(listek, b)
listek <- rbind(listek, d)
names(listek) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

And here is results:

```
 [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]     
b "hehe" "hoho" "hihi" Numeric,6
d "ddd"  "eee"  "fff"  Numeric,6
attr(,"names")
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Why I don't have same result like in first example? How I fix this or what I doing wrong?
I want this result:

```
$a
[1] "hehe"
[2] "ddd"

$b
[1] "hoho"
[2] "eee"

$c
[1] "hihi"
[2] "fff"
$d
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 2
[2] 1,3,5,6,6,7
```

Comment: The length of `listek` is 8. You need 8 names.

Comment: @Pascal If I put 8 names is same. I got attribut names without NA. I want only 4 names for each column one name.

Comment: Is the structure what you expected (aside from names) - i.e. do you really want to `rbind` those lists together? If so, and you are trying to name the columns, use `colnames`.

Comment: @jbaums I thing rbind is easy way to adding some rows, when I don't in start create rows.

Comment: I agree with @jbaums. Please first check if what you are doing is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for `setNames(Map(rbind, b,d), letters[1:4])`?

Comment: I update what I want

Comment: Well now it's clear. It's always a good idea to include your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setNames(Map(rbind, b,d), letters[1:4])
#    $a
#     [,1]  
#[1,] "hehe"
#[2,] "ddd" 

#$b
#     [,1]  
#[1,] "hoho"
#[2,] "eee" 

#$c
#     [,1]  
#[1,] "hihi"
#[2,] "fff" 

#$d
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    6    2
# [2,]    1    3    5    6    6    7
```